# In optimization, when can we turn an inf to a min?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Suppose that an optimization problem is written as

$\inf_{x \in C} f(x)$

Under what assumption on $C$ can we turn it to a $\min$?

I think Weierstrass's theorem says that minimizer is guaranteed to exist whenever $f$ is continuous over a compact $C$.

Can we relax the assumption on $C$?

Comment: You can use a min when it's guaranteed to exist. The inf of a bounded set of reals always exists, but for the min to exist, you need the inf to be in the set. Let's relax. If $C$ is not compact for instance: what's the inf of $x\to\dfrac1{1+x^2}$ on $\Bbb R$? What's the min?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I wonder if we can change $C$ to be closed, but with some additional assumption on $f$

Comment: @I just gave you such an example. And $f$ is as smooth as you can hope. Maybe you have "convex" in mind: then try $x\to \exp(x)$. Basically you need to be sure the inf is not at infinity. But you may just as well take a restriction of $f$ on a compact that contains the inf.